# positioning numbers after text

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have added a paragraph style that has numbering in it. I was wondering how I make the numbers come after the text? I have tried aligning the number to the right but that doesn't work.

Comment: I personally, for such things (e.g. TOC) did second text frame for numbers. At other have you can do a table with two columns - the second column for numbers.

Comment: Did you try a right-align tab with a leader character?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum how would you do that?

Comment: Instructions on how to set tabs in InDesign are easily found under the Help menu and on the web. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6dbba.html

Answer (score 1):

Best work-around:

- remove the numbering from the paragraph
- add a last line indent to the paragraph style which will clear for the numbers
- add a new paragraph style which is right-aligned and automatically numbers and is set to keep w/ the previous paragraph and has zero-leading
- add such additional paragraphs using that paragraph style where you want the numbering.